# Star rating in AJAX with Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, rating

I think that acts_as_rateable seems to be quite obsolete and doesn't support AJAX.

I'm looking for a simple "5 star" rating system: is there any plugin or tutorial that can help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [ajaxful-rating plugin](http://github.com/edgarjs/ajaxful-rating/tree/master).

Comment: Great plugin! It is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Prego! :D (dannati 15 caratteri del commento...)

Comment: StackOverflow requires you to post in English. However, you comment is not.

Comment: As of Rails 3.1, there is a gem for a simple to use jquery star rating system: https://github.com/RichGuk/jquery-star-rating-rails

Answer (score 24):

Fully a year later, since this is one of the top hits on Google for this subject I thought I'd add this note:

Ajaxful rating doesn't really work on Rails 3, so you might want to check out this tutorial for how to create your own star rating system in Rails 3.
(http://eighty-b.tumblr.com/post/1569674815/creating-an-ajaxified-star-rating-system-in-rails-3)